# change number of columns in wordpress child theme

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, grid

how can I change the HTML markup of bootstrap grid in my wordpress child theme?

I have this markup in the child theme

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 footer-sidebar-wrap">
```

and would like to change the column width to

```
.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4
```

is there a way to override this is the custom CSS editor?

thanks!

Comment: Just change the css classes in your html from <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 footer-sidebar-wrap"> to <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 footer-sidebar-wrap"> and add the third such column. Is not it what you are looking for?

Comment: have tried this but the changes don't register....i think i'm missign something in the footer.php file

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to change with CSS:

```
.footer-sidebar-wrap.col-sm-6.col-md-3 {
  /* Copy ALL style rules for .col-xs-6 and .col-sm-4 here. */
}
```

It's a bad idea, though, for maintainability reasons. Better to take @Nick Surmanidze's advice in his comment and change the html in the template.

Answer (score 0):

here is the current footer.php file that I'm trying to edit

```
<?php
/**
 * Template functions used for the site footer.
 *
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 'shop_isle_footer_widgets' ) ) {
    /**
     * Display the footer widgets
     * @since  1.0.0
     * @return void
     */
    function shop_isle_footer_widgets() {
        ?>
        <!-- Widgets start -->

    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-footer-area-1' ) || is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-footer-area-2' ) || is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-footer-area-3' ) || is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-footer-area-4' ) ) : ?>

        <div class="module-small bg-dark shop_isle_footer_sidebar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-footer-area-1' ) ) : ?>
                        <div class=".col-xs-6 .col-sm-4 footer-sidebar-wrap">
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-footer-area-1'); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <!-- Widgets end -->

                    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-footer-area-2' ) ) : ?>
                        <div class=".col-xs-6 .col-sm-4 footer-sidebar-wrap">
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-footer-area-2'); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <!-- Widgets end -->

                    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-footer-area-3' ) ) : ?>
                        <div class=".col-xs-6 .col-sm-4 footer-sidebar-wrap">
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-footer-area-3'); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <!-- Widgets end -->

                </div><!-- .row -->
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'shop_isle_footer_copyright_and_socials' ) ) {
    /**
     * Display the theme copyright and socials
     * @since  1.0.0
     * @return void
     */
    function shop_isle_footer_copyright_and_socials() {

        ?>
        <!-- Footer start -->
        <footer class="footer bg-dark">
            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="divider-d">
            <!-- Divider -->
            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">

                    <?php
                    /* Copyright */
                    $shop_isle_copyright = get_theme_mod('shop_isle_copyright',__( '&copy; Themeisle, All rights reserved', 'shop-isle' ));
                    if( !empty($shop_isle_copyright) ):
                        echo '<div class="col-sm-6">';
                            echo '<p class="copyright font-alt">'.$shop_isle_copyright.'</p>';
                            $shop_isle_site_info_hide = get_theme_mod('shop_isle_site_info_hide');
                            if( isset($shop_isle_site_info_hide) && $shop_isle_site_info_hide != 1 ): ?>
                            <p class="shop-isle-poweredby-box"><a class="shop-isle-poweredby" href="http://themeisle.com/themes/shop-isle/" rel="nofollow">ShopIsle </a><?php _e('powered by','shop-isle'); ?><a class="shop-isle-poweredby" href="http://wordpress.org/" rel="nofollow"> WordPress</a></p>
                            <?php
                            endif;
                        echo '</div>';
                    endif;

                    /* Socials icons */

                    $shop_isle_socials = get_theme_mod('shop_isle_socials',json_encode(array( array('icon_value' => 'social_facebook' ,'link' => '#' ),array('icon_value' => 'social_twitter' ,'link' => '#'), array('icon_value' => 'social_dribbble' ,'link' => '#'), array('icon_value' => 'social_skype' ,'link' => '#') )));

                    if( !empty( $shop_isle_socials ) ):

                        $shop_isle_socials_decoded = json_decode($shop_isle_socials);

                        if( !empty($shop_isle_socials_decoded) ):

                            echo '<div class="col-sm-6">';

                                echo '<div class="footer-social-links">';

                                    foreach($shop_isle_socials_decoded as $shop_isle_social):

                                        if( !empty($shop_isle_social->icon_value) && !empty($shop_isle_social->link) ) {

                                            if (function_exists ( 'icl_t' ) && !empty($shop_isle_social->id)){



                                                $shop_isle_social_icon_value = icl_t( 'Social '.$shop_isle_social->id, 'Social icon', $shop_isle_social->icon_value );

                                                $shop_isle_social_link = icl_t( 'Social '.$shop_isle_social->id, 'Social link', $shop_isle_social->link );



                                                echo '<a href="'. esc_url( $shop_isle_social_link ) .'"><span class="'.$shop_isle_social_icon_value.'"></span></a>';        

                                            } else {

                                                echo '<a href="'.esc_url($shop_isle_social->link).'"><span class="'.$shop_isle_social->icon_value.'"></span></a>';                  
                                            }

                                        }

                                    endforeach;

                                echo '</div>';

                            echo '</div>';

                        endif;

                    endif;
                    ?>
                </div><!-- .row -->

            </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- Footer end -->
        <?php
    }
}


if ( ! function_exists( 'shop_isle_footer_wrap_open' ) ) {
    /**
     * Display the theme copyright and socials
     * @since  1.0.0
     * @return void
     */
    function shop_isle_footer_wrap_open() {
        echo '</div><div class="bottom-page-wrap">';
    }

}


if ( ! function_exists( 'shop_isle_footer_wrap_close' ) ) {
    /**
     * Display the theme copyright and socials
     * @since  1.0.0
     * @return void
     */
    function shop_isle_footer_wrap_close() {
        echo '</div><!-- .bottom-page-wrap -->';
    }

}
```

Comment: I changed the class to <div class=".col-xs-6 .col-sm-4 footer-sidebar-wrap"> and deleted footer area 4 but the changes still aren't registering

Comment: seems like the changes in the child theme footer.php file aren't loading but only reads from the original footer.php parent theme. how to override this?